# Executing Remote Command via Powershell in Azure with no script

Tags: azure, powershell

I am trying to setup Azure VM's using Powershell but i wish to do it all remotely with no logging into the machine. I have been able to spin up the VM using commands like New-AzVM but now i need to run specific powershell commands e.g. Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName IIS-ManagementConsole

I can see you can run remote scripts using the following but as this is a brand new server there are no scripts on that box to execute.

```
 Invoke-AzVMRunCommand -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -Name $VmName -CommandId 'RunPowerShellScript' -ScriptPath '<pathToScript>' -Parameter @{"arg1" = "var1";"arg2" = "var2"}
```

How can i copy scripts to the server remotely so i can use the above command, or run commands without the need for a script file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to copy the scripts remotely to the Azure VM. You can run it locally.

Save the PowerShell scripts to a format `.ps1` file, then run it on local PowerShell with referencing the path of the script via parameter `-ScriptPath`.

```
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName IIS-ManagementConsole
```

You also could copy that scripts on the Virtual machine---Run command---RunPowerShellScript on the Azure portal, refer to [this](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/itops-talk-blog/how-to-run-scripts-on-azure-virtual-machines-with-the-run/ba-p/292446).

Answer (score 0):

What you need is to look into the direction of PowerShell Desired State Configuration (DSC)

1. [Here you can find general explanation for this technology](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/dsc/overview/overview?view=powershell-7)
2. [Get started manual for DSC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/dsc/getting-started/wingettingstarted?view=powershell-7)